# How to filter Integerlist from a Array list field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am using Django Admin (list_filter) to filter a list of Integers form a array list field am not getting any result query.

```
model.py

class Offer(CreatedAndUpdatedMixin):
     stores = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),default=list(),
              null=True, blank=True)
```

below is my custom lookup code in `filter.py`

```
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
      if self.value() == 'Bangalore':
        stores = Store.objects.filter(city__id=1).values_list('id', flat=True)
        return queryset.filter(stores__contains=list(stores))
      return queryset
```

Am not geting any errors but returns empty

Comment: Can you try to change `contains` with `overlap`? In documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap), if I understand correctly, overlap suits your use case.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I've posted this as an answer to help people to find easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `contains` with `overlap`. As [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap) mentioned, `overlap` is used for the case to find records matches with the given array.